# Copy all directories to server by FTP using Java

Tags: java, recursion, ftp

I need to copy a directory from the local disk to a server. 
The directory contains a lot of directories, subdirectories, and files. (Think of a hierarchy tree of directories).

Here is an example to copy one file:

```
 public void saveFilesToServer() throws IOException {
    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
    ftp.connect(ftp.foobar.com);
    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftp.getReplyCode())) {
        ftp.disconnect();
        log.fatal("FTP not disconnected");
    }

    ftp.login("foo", "qwerty");
    log.info("Connected to server .");
    log.info(ftp.getReplyString());
    ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("test");
    ftp.makeDirectory("somedir");
    ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("somedir");
    ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);    
    java.io.File srcFolder = new java.io.File(folderPath);      
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(srcFolder);
    ftp.storeFile (fileName, fis);
    ftp.disconnect();
    log.info("FTP disconnected");
}
```

Now, I need to copy a directory (`somedir`) with all the subdirectories and files of `somedir`.

I think the algorithm should use recursion.
Does someone know how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following is an example of a recursive solution to the problem:

```
public void saveFilesToServer(String remoteDest, File localSrc) throws IOException {
    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
    ftp.connect("ftp.foobar.com");
    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftp.getReplyCode())) {
        ftp.disconnect();
        log.fatal("FTP not disconnected");
    }

    ftp.login("foo", "qwerty");
    log.info("Connected to server .");
    log.info(ftp.getReplyString());

    ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(remoteDest);
    ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

    try {
        upload(localSrc, ftp);
    }
    finally {
        ftp.disconnect();
        log.info("FTP disconnected");           
    }
}

public void upload(File src, FTPClient ftp) throws IOException {
    if (src.isDirectory()) {
        ftp.makeDirectory(src.getName());
        ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(src.getName());
        for (File file : src.listFiles()) {
            upload(file, ftp);
        }
        ftp.changeToParentDirectory();
    }
    else {
        InputStream srcStream = null;
        try {
            srcStream = src.toURI().toURL().openStream();
            ftp.storeFile(src.getName(), srcStream);
        }
        finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(srcStream);
        }
    }
}
```

[`IOUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) is a part of [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/).

Comment: have helped me though I code in C++. Algorithm is just the same!

Answer (score -2):

```
upload(fileName){
  If (filename is not dir){
   ftpFile();
   return;
 }
 listoffiles = get the list of all files in dir 
    for each file : listoffiles {
    upload(file)
 }
```

}