# FTP Recursive File Upload, Download and Delete

Tags: c++, ftp, wxwidgets

I use wxFTP to make simple client and I'm stucked on how to Upload recursively my folder or do download (which would should be same as delete) from FTP server. I know how to upload single file, make FTP folder and delete file. I will appreciate an article (not necessarily in C/C++) that teaches the concept or if someone can help me here.

Code example will be appreciated but take that as secondary. 
Sorry if it already asked and answered, I searched and didn't get anything that answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I translated the code in answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718843/copy-all-directories-to-server-by-ftp-using-java)  question to C++ and that was it.
Since So won't accept the answer and adds it to comments I have added Java code that I translated to C++. My current code is too long (in that it involves few functions and so not fit for SO I guess!

```
    public void saveFilesToServer(String remoteDest, File localSrc) throws IOException {
    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
    ftp.connect("ftp.foobar.com");
    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftp.getReplyCode())) {
        ftp.disconnect();
        log.fatal("FTP not disconnected");
    }

    ftp.login("foo", "qwerty");
    log.info("Connected to server .");
    log.info(ftp.getReplyString());

    ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(remoteDest);
    ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

    try {
        upload(localSrc, ftp);
    }
    finally {
        ftp.disconnect();
        log.info("FTP disconnected");           
    }
}

public void upload(File src, FTPClient ftp) throws IOException {
    if (src.isDirectory()) {
        ftp.makeDirectory(src.getName());
        ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(src.getName());
        for (File file : src.listFiles()) {
            upload(file, ftp);
        }
        ftp.changeToParentDirectory();
    }
    else {
        InputStream srcStream = null;
        try {
            srcStream = src.toURI().toURL().openStream();
            ftp.storeFile(src.getName(), srcStream);
        }
        finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(srcStream);
        }
    }
}
```